# Crossplatform webview in Qt5.6

Tags: mingw, qt5, qtwebkit, qwebview, qtwebengine

I am using **Qt 5.6 with MinGW on Windows 10 64x** for developing a cross platform app (desktop + mobile).

In Qt 5.5, I could use WebKit to make a cross platform app for showing web pages in my app, and I could use it on Windows, Android, iOs...
Today, I realized we can't use it anymore, we can't use `QtWebView` neither for Windows and also can't use `QtWebEngine` with MinGW.

Thus, I am confused : knowing that I want to show a webpage using my current configuration (for android desktop and mobile version), what should I do?

Is there a hope it will be solved in the next Qt versions?

**Edit:**
Even when I want to run Qt special webview (minibrowser) example, it shows qmake error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in Qt: webenginewidgets
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in Qt: webview
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use MinGW for the web engine with Qt. It is said [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-platform-notes.html):

> Windows: Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015

and you can find more information on [this page](http://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngineOnWindows). Also, the fact that MinGW can't be used with Qt WebEngine has been reported as bugs (e.g. [42725](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42725)) and it is explained :

> It is very unlikely that Chromium itself will support MinGW, and likewise it would be a lot of work for the QtWebEngine team to achieve this. It is quite a shame that Qt MinGW packages will be incomplete because of this.

Chromium is the browser integrated by `QWebEngine`, and in `QWebkit` the browser integrated was WebKit, hence the fact you can't use MinGW anymore for `QWebEngine`.

Comment: No problem, I hope that helps, even if it sucks that Qt WebEngine can't be played along with MinGW :/

Comment: can i hope this will be solved in the next versions of Qt?
and can i hope to fix and develop Webview for all platforms and so on mingw?

Comment: Unfortunately, only if MinGW supports Chromium one day, and I don't think so... Now that Qt WebKit is deprecated, the only thing you can do is using Visual Studio for Qt WebEngine. Many people disagree with Qt WebKit being no longer supported

Comment: Does anyone know of any new developments in this department or is the situation still exactly the same?

Comment: In the bug report it seems like progress on porting to MinGW was done and they got it working but there's no mention if it's actaully finished. Has anyone tested this?