# trying to build source in QT Creator 5.7

Tags: qt

i am trying building browser source code in Qt Creator 5.7 using WebEbgine on windows mingw,
But it is showing the following error while building

error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets

Can anybody help in this, how to resolve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crossplatform webview in Qt5.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852346/crossplatform-webview-in-qt5-6)

Comment: MinGW is not supported for webengine, sorry

Comment: Its Qt, not QT, and Creator is just an IDE and is currently at version 4.1 or so...

Comment: thanks, any solution to this problem?